# Find controls caption and change it state

Tags: delphi, controls, disabled-control

I have form with enabled / disabled controls to indicate form is in busy or idle state. 
I need to enable only ONE control (a button, but could be else), when it was disabled to abort some process. I change the button caption to 'ABORT'.

I click button A, i change the caption of button A to 'ABORT'. All other control will be disabled, but i want a button with caption 'ABORT' is still enabled.

```
procedure F1.FormBusy (sender);
var
  a: Integer;
begin
  for a := 0 to TabSheet1.ControlCount - 1 do
  begin
    TabSheet1.Controls[a].Enabled := False;
    (* if TabSheet1.Controls[a] caption := 'ABORT' then
      TabSheet1.Controls[a].Enabled := True
      < how to do this ? *)
  end;
end;
```

Usage example :

```
procedure F1.LB1Click(sender: TObject);
begin
  FormBusy(sender);
  try
    // do something
  finally
    FormIdle(sender);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: @TomBrunberg some times i use `TComboBox` clicks.

Comment: Why not just use the control reference directly

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Is it like @Owen given answer ? Yes, this is new to me. It is working good. But is there any more simple method, just like that `formbusy` and `formdile` ?

Comment: Yes. Do this with actions

Comment: I upvote any question that was downvoted and no reason was provided for the downvote !!!!

Answer (score 5):

Rather than trying to find the button by its Caption property, why not access it directly from the array?

```
for a := 0 to TabSheet1.ControlCount - 1 do
begin
  TabSheet1.Controls[a].Enabled := TabSheet1.Controls[a] = Button1;
end;
```

Each TControl will be disabled except for Button1 which will be enabled.

Comment: I manage my form busy / idle by `FormBusy (sender)` and  `FormIdle (sender)`. So now, i will need to place that code on each button, am i right ?

Comment: That code would go inside your FormBusy() method, so when you put the form into its "busy" state, controls other than "ABORT" are disabled.  You'd need to add additional code to FormIdle() method in order to re-enable the appropriate controls when moving back to an "idle" state.

Comment: It's working good, Owen. Thanks. But i have many buttons. How placing the code in FormBusy()?

Answer (score 1):

You can define another method to assign busy parameter :

```
procedure F1.MAJIHM(const isBusy : Boolean);
var a: Integer;
begin
  for a := 0 to TabSheet1.ControlCount - 1 do
  begin
    TabSheet1.Controls[a].Enabled := isBusy;
  end;
  btnABORT.enabled := not isBusy;
end;

procedure F1.FormBusy (sender);
begin
  MAJIHM(True);
end;

procedure F1.FormIdle (sender);
begin
  MAJIHM(False);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> I click button A, i change the caption of button A to 'ABORT'. All
>   other control will be disabled, but i want a button with caption
>   'ABORT' is still enabled.

And from your usage example it is clear that you pass that button to `F1.FormBusy()` where you can refer to it as the `sender` parameter:

```
procedure F1.FormBusy(sender: TObject);
var
  a: Integer;
begin
  for a := 0 to TabSheet1.ControlCount - 1 do
    TabSheet1.Controls[a].Enabled := TabSheet1.Controls[a] = sender;
end;
```

In the `FormIdle()` function you simply enable **all** controls.